# Is gaming.stackexchange.com a "Minecraft and some other games" site?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

Just out of curiosity:

Having fun reading here on Gaming, it seems to me that 95% of all questions are about Minecraft.

Is this intended/true or should one even consider creating a Minecraft only StackExchange website? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: A few months ago, Gaming was "all" Starcraft 2, "all" the time. It depends both on how many people on this site play a certain game and on how many people playing a certain game end up on our site... and by how well the game lends itself to having questions that can't be easily answered ingame. :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait until the hype is over :-)

Comment: Also - I see you haven't setup any ignored or interesting tag. If you're not interested in seeing Minecraft questions you can use that feature to "dim" them down.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Currently, about 5.3% of all questions on Gaming.SE are tagged Minecraft, which is a lot, but not an absurdly high percentage. I think it takes more than just a lot of questions on a topic to justify creating a "spin-off" SE. A while back, I tried to document some of my thoughts on this [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/83/game-specific-sites/296#296).

Comment: At the time of posting this comment, ~9.25% of questions on Stack Overflow are tagged C#. (Just a reference.)

Comment: @Kevin Wow, I would have a completely different feeling regarding those number. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick I don't think emulating the "duplicate of" message with nonexistent questions is appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there too many StarCraft 2 / single game questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/923/are-there-too-many-starcraft-2-single-game-questions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gaming is for all video games.  At various time people have complained that it seems all the questions are for Starcraft 2, or Minecraft, or Portal 2, etc.  The questions on the site are the ones people ask, and we neither exclude games nor try to force a balance between games.  So feel free to ask questions about any game you want.

Comment: I'll do, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Just as a corollary: [This is relevant](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go)

Comment: This is probably the best way to change the perception that Gaming has a lot of questions on Game X: come up with a question about another game and post it!

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't a simple visit to

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags

provide data that indicates [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) cannot *possibly* be "95 percent" of the site?

Comment: I think he was exaggerating a bit.

Comment: @gnome I've told you a *million* times to stop exaggerating.

Comment: Sorry, also having around 3k points in Stack Overflow, I still know very few things about your large community system. I tried to search for "Minecraft" here through Meta but didn't even think about the tags. Please excuse this!

Answer (score 3):

This is because Minecraft just released a new version.  Whenever a new game comes out or an existing game releases a new version, there is a period when many of the new questions relate to that game.

Answer (score -6):

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>
> - Is gaming.stackexchange.com a "StarCraft II and some other games" site?
> - Is gaming.stackexchange.com a "Portal 2 and some other games" site?
> - Is gaming.stackexchange.com a "Team Fortress 2 and some other games" site?

Comment: So I asked a really bad question, is that what you want to tell me? Again, please take my apologies. Would it help in any way if I delete my question?

Comment: @Uwe this is mostly in jest, as said variants of your question seem to crop up from time-to-time depending on what's the flavor of the month.  It's not an inherently bad question.

Comment: This still isn't appropriate as an answer.

Comment: The Witcher 2. :/ Perhaps "Is Gaming.SE an unimaginative sequel Q&A site?"